# A user doesn't have any persmission when its account has just been created in Firebase (web version), why?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, firebase-security

I'm trying to use Firebase in the web project (with NextJS), but here is my problem: the user doesn't have an account, so naturally the account is created with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`. However, I want to store data in Firestore right after the creation of the account... and there is the problem. Indeed Firebase throws the following error:

> FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Here is an extract of my code:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  getAuth,
} from "firebase/auth";
import {
  collection,
  getFirestore,
  addDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";

export const ConnectionPage = () => {
  // the values of the inputs in the HTML content
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  // the function executed when the user clicks the register button
  const submit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // create a new user with email and password
    // and add the document in the "users" collection
    try {
      const userCredentials = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        getAuth(),
        email,
        password
      );
      const user = userCredentials.user;
      const userInfo = {
        uid: user.uid,
        // ...and all kind of data
      };
      const collectionRef = collection(getFirestore(), "users");
      // my problem starts here
      // the following line will throw an error
      // "[code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions."
      // whereas, according to the rules in Firestore, it should work
      // because I just ask the user to be authenticated (`allow write, read: if request.auth != null`)
      // and according to the documentation, `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` logs in the user.
      const docRef = await addDoc(collectionRef, userInfo);
      console.log(`New document with id '${docRef.id}' created successfully.`);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("An error has occured during register, look:");
      console.error(e.toString());
    }
  };

  // returns a form
  // with an email input
  // and a password input
  // and a button to register
};
```

Here are my rules in Firestore:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow write, read: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me, the only solution I can find on a similar problem is to sign out the user after the creation of the account, and sign in right after that.

I tried:

- in-promise syntax (`.then()`) but the problem is the same than with `async/await`
- `onAuthStateChanged()`, but the same problem occurs.
- Changing the rules to something more complex (like testing the existence of the user according to the `request.auth.uid`) doesn't work either.

Comment: The code `collection(getFirestore(), "users")` should never fail, because it never reaches out to the service and requires no permissions.  It is just creating a reference to a collection.  It's on until the next line of code where you call `addDoc` that anything happens on Firestore.

Comment: All right, I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is fixed thanks to the contributors I talked to in GitHub. The problem was coming from the App Check feature which does not work with Firestore until the version `9.6.0`.

The solution is:

```
npm install firebase@9.6.0
```

By default, `npm install firebase` is installing version `9.5.0`.

Note that this version is recent and if you see that message in 2031 it's completely useless.

Thank to the people who answered me :)

Answer (score 0):

When you just have:

```
allow read;
```

This is an entire statement, and means that nobody can read the data.

If you want to apply the same condition for both read and write, use:

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

Comment: I still have the same error ;( My goal is to have that permission when the account is created

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) instead of just `await` on the creation of the account.  In my experience, the current user object is not immediately set after account creation, and you have to wait until the auth state observer triggers with a non-null user object in order to be able to perform authenticated queries.  Without a non-null currentUser, Firestore queries that require auth will fail.

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

If this feels like a bug to you, then I suggest filing it on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk).

Comment: Nothing works, this is definitely not a normal behaviour according to me. I will report that as a bug on GitHub

Comment: When you say "nothing works", it's a good idea to back that up with all of the things you actually tried, especially the auth state observer that is shown in the product documentation.  Please edit the question to show everything that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: All right, let me add details